# Parse error unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in php with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using php 5.5.9 and I'm having trouble with "use", this is my code:

```
require_once 'KnpLabs/src/autoload.php';

use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

$snappy = new Pdf('C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://localhost/pdfTester/try.php');
```

And this is my error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Invesments\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\single-inversion.php on line 184

Comment: What's in the required file?

Comment: I don't see a current namespace declaration

Comment: https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy <--- I'm following this documentation and it seems many people use it and it works for them

Comment: can you post the whole file including `<?php` ?